# Creating server with C sockets and getting error

Tags: c, sockets, httpserver

I'm following a tutorial for creating an HTTP server with sockets using C. I'm on Windows using the gcc compiler. The server runs and I can even hit it and get data back when using a custom client built from C sockets. But When I try run the command

> `"curl -o - http://127.0.0.1:8001"`

to connect to my server, I receive the error:

```
curl : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
host.
```

My server output shows the connection is trying to be made, but doesn't show any errors. Here is my code..
http_server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    //open a file to server
    FILE *html_data;
    html_data = fopen("index.html", "r");
    
    
    
    char response_data[1024];
    fgets(response_data, 1024, html_data);
    
    char http_header[2048] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
    strcat(http_header, response_data);
    
    
    
    //create a socket
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    
    // specify an address for the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8001);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
    //bind the socket to our specified IP and port
    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket,5);

    int client_socket;
    

    
while(1) {

    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
    
    printf("client socket response: %d\n", client_socket);
    perror("socket");
    send(client_socket, http_header, sizeof(http_header),0);
    close(client_socket);

}

    
    return 0;

}
```

index.html

```
<html><body>welcome to the HTTP Server!</body></html>
```

Comment: `http_header` is 2048 bytes. But your response is probably less than that. Yet you send all 2048 bytes, many which are zero. You should send `strlen(http_header)` bytes instead.

Comment: You also claim in the response header to be HTTP/1.1, but you're really not. There's no `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and especially no `Connection` headers.

Comment: Hmm. I changed it to strlen(http_header) but the error is the same. I will try adding those you listed to my header. I was following the tutorial here where he doesn't have those listed, but still manages to hit the server from Chrome: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mStnzIEprH8&t=18m25s

Comment: On another note, the value of `errno` (used by `perror`) is indeterminate unless the unless the *previous* function actually failed. You not only use `errno` even when `accept` didn't fail, you also use it after `printf` which might have changed its value.

Comment: Where in the header should these values go?

Comment: Please do some more research about [HTTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're pretty close to getting it working. The reason `curl` is complaining is because it's expecting you to have supplied a `Content-Length` header. You can do this by updating your existing code as follows:

```c
    char response_data[1024];
    fgets(response_data, 1024, html_data);

    size_t message_length = strlen(response_data);

    char http_header[2048];
    snprintf(http_header, sizeof(http_header), "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %zu\r\n\r\n", message_length);
    strcat(http_header, response_data);
```

You also need to update your send code to only send the length of the response string.

```c
    send(client_socket, http_header, strlen(http_header),0);
```

You still have some issues with your error checking as mentioned in the comments, but at least with these changes `curl` should be happy.

---

While what I mentioned above is the minimal headers that will satisfy `curl`, there are others that you need to add to make you code conform to [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

```
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```